# Ввод в массив функции python

Tags: python, массивы, функции

Следущий код удаляет **не** уникальные элементы из массива. Однако хочется реализовать его через функцию и вводить элементы из клавиатуры или через вызов функции.

```
array = [1,3,2,3,6,7,4]
sorted = array[:]

for i in array:
    if array.count(i) == 1:
        array.remove(i)
print(sorted)
```

**UPD:** 
Спасибо всем за советы! Вроде получилось как хотел:

```
def func(data):
    data = input().split()
    e = data[:]

    for i in data:
        if data.count(i) == 1:
            e.remove(i)
    print(e)
    return e

func(print())
```

Comment: new_array = [i for i in array if array.count(i) > 1]

как переписать эту строку в столбец? Блоки остаются?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Еще один вариант решения:

```
data_list = []

while True:
    num = raw_input(">")
    if num == "":
        break
    else:
        data_list.append(num)
        continue

def sort_list(mylist):
    result_list = []

    for num in mylist:
        if num in result_list:
            continue
        else:
            result_list.append(num)
    return result_list

print sort_list(data_list)
```

Пример вывода:

```
>1
>2
>1
>6
>
['1', '2', '6']
```

Comment: Не понятно назначение sort_list - ТС просит о другом: надо удалить те элементы, которые встречаются только 1 раз. Т.е. в вашем случае надо было оставить только две единицы.

Comment: ТС вроде как функцией сделать просил, нет?
Да и пишет: "Следущий код удаляет не уникальные элементы из массива."
Мой код это и делает, а вот что делает его код, мне до сих пор не понятно.

Comment: Ну если пример КАК сделать функцией - то пойдет) А если пример самой  функции - то нет)

Просто не понятно - то ли вы специально так написали, то ли задачу не поняли)

Comment: Ну видимо не понял задачи. Ибо ТС написал что код удаляет НЕ уникальные значения. Это я и написал, а выходит что надо было сделать на оборот.

Comment: `while True` цикл можно заменить на `items = iter(lambda: raw_input('>'), '')` (где `raw_input = input` так как код в вопросе похож на Питон 3). Вместо `sort_list()`, чтобы удалить повторы: `uniq = set(items)`.

Answer (score 4):

[python sets](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html)

```
def sort_list(mylist):
    result_list = []

    for num in mylist:
        if num in result_list:
            continue
        else:
            result_list.append(num)
    return result_list
```

заменяем на

```
def sort_list(mylist):
    return list(set(mylist))
```

Answer (score 2):

Для 2.7:
1. Ввод с клавиатуры:

```
array = raw_input().split()
```

вводим числа разделенные пробелом - получаем массив чисел (точнее - строк, которые можно привести к числам через `map`)
2. удалять из того же массива по которому проходишь - вроде как не есть хорошо, лучше либо сохранять копию и удалять из нее, либо помещать удаляемые элементы в другой массив, а потом удалять из исходного все сохраненные элементы,

Можно сделать так:

```
new_array = [i for i in array if array.count(i) > 1]
```

new_array будет содержать не уникальные элементы

*Обновление*

Ну так что мешает эту конструкцию обернуть в функцию? Первую часть вы тем более уже написали:

```
def func(data):
    ... # здесь мой код с заменой array на data
    return new_array
```

И все.

Comment: Спасибо!
 А как можно привести к функции типа:
def func(data):
....
return 
func([1,2,5,5,2])

upd. В комментах нет подвески кода, я имею вышеуказанный пример сделать функцией и вызвать её с аргументам

Comment: автор просит удалить элементы, которые более одного раза встречаются. У вас код обратное делает, используя квадратичный алгоритм. `new_array = set(array)` убирает повторы (линейное время).

Comment: @jfs, автор просит одно, в коде у него совсем другое (в том числе, в том, который в вопросе как правильный отмечен), я ориентировался на код )). И set здесь не сработает, т.к. set([1,1,2]) вернет [1,2], а надо только 1 (т.к. 2 встречается только 1 раз), либо 2 (т.к. 1 встречается несколько раз). Если гнаться за линейностью, то можно создать словарь, в котором ключи - элементы, а значения - количество повторов. Первый проход - заполняем словарь, второй проход - создаем список из словаря, где количество элементов равно 1

Comment: @BOPOH я знаю что set делает и явно уже это сказал: "убирает повторы" (aba -> ab) 1- что по вашему sort_list в принятом ответе делает? 2- у вас код похож на "получилось как хотел" код в вопросе (aba-> a — **сохраняет** не уникальные элементы), но автор вероятно не понимает, что код именно это делает (принятый ответ содержит явно результаты (1216->126)—не требует понимания кода).  3- не предлагайте квадратичный алгоритм вместо линейного если заранее неизвестно что ввод маленький или по меньшей мере  упомяните явно `O(n**2)` (я не сомневаюсь что вы можете линейный алгоритм найти).

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы прочитать с клавиатуры строку, содержащую элементы через пробел, и убрать повторы (чтобы в итоговой коллекции все элементы были бы уникальны):

```
uniq_items = set(input('Input: ').split())
```

На Питоне 2, используйте `raw_input()`, вместо `input()`.

В данном случае роль искомой функции выполняет `set`. Разделяйте ввод/вывод и функции для анализа данных—легче функции писать/тестировать, когда ввода/вывода в них нет.