# Вернуть массив, состоящий только из неуникальных элементов данного массива

Tags: python, алгоритм, python-3.x

```
def A(number) :

    for item in range(len(number)) :
        if number.count(item) < 2 : # определяю уникальный или нет
            number[item] *= 0       # превращаю уникальный в ноль

            for i, elem in enumerate(number) :
                if elem == 0 :
                    del number[i]    # если ноль - удаляю
                    return number
```

Дан непустой массив целых чисел. Нужно вернуть массив, состоящий только из неуникальных элементов данного массива. Для этого необходимо удалить все уникальные элементы (которые присутствуют в данном массиве только один раз). Нельзя менять оригинальный порядок элементов.

Мой код работает, но убирает только первый уникальный элемент, а остальные не трогает.Почему, не знаю, но хотел бы узнать.

Если дается [1, 2, 3, 3, 3] , то должно вернуться - [3, 3, 3]. А у меня возвращается - [2, 3, 3, 3].

Comment: связанный вопрос: [Ввод в массив функции python](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/332019/23044)

Comment: связанный вопрос: [В чем разница между двумя циклами for: при удалении элементов во время обхода списка](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/596463/23044)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот в этом куске

```
for i, elem in enumerate(number) :
    if elem == 0 :
        del number[i]    # если ноль - удаляю
```

Вы удаляете элементы из того списка, по которому итерируетесь. Так делать нельзя, иначе после удаления элемента цикл будет перескакивать через следующий элемент (потому что после удаления предыдущего он сдвинулся на его место).

Поэтому некоторые элементы у вас и не удаляются - в цикле они просто проскальзывают мимо.

Вообще, нужно стараться заменять циклы списковыми выражениями там, где это возможно.

Например, вашу функцию можно написать в одну строчку:

```
def A(number) :
  return [i for i in number if number.count(i) > 1]
```

Comment: пожалуйста, не предлагайте квадратичный алгоритм вместо линейного, если заранее неизвестно что ввод маленький или по меньшей мере упомяните явно `O(n**2)`, особенно в ответе на простой вопрос, когда люди могут не осознавать big O операций типа `number.count(i)`.

Comment: @jfs, согласен, алгоритм не оптимален. Но я просто лаконично переписал тот же алгоритм, который у автора и так был.

Comment: в вопросе код сломанный, поэтому как для самого автора так и для людей с похожей проблемой приземлившихся здесь из поисковика (сайт в основном для второй категории людей существует—иначе и ответы и разрешённые вопросы были бы другие), следует упомянуть если в коде есть очевидные вам проблемы (тем более что если нет специальных потребностей, то есть [простое решение в две строчки](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/621477/23044)). Я в конце ответа проиллюстрировал [разницу между линейным и квадратичным алгоритмом](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/596513/23044)

Answer (score 7):

Линейный алгоритм по времени и памяти (`O(n)` - время, `O(n)` - память), который новый список возвращает, содержащий элементы, которые встречаются более одного раза, сохраняя порядок исходного списка:

```
from collections import Counter

def non_uniq(numbers):
    counter = Counter(numbers)
    return [n for n in numbers if counter[n] > 1]
```

Пример из вопроса:

```
>>> non_uniq([1, 2, 3, 3, 3])
[3, 3, 3]
```

Если одинаковые элементы всегда рядом, можно однопроходный алгоритм, использующий только постоянную память (`O(n)` - время, `O(1)` - память):

```
from itertools import groupby, islice

def non_uniq_adjacent(sorted_numbers, min_repeat=2):
    for _, same in groupby(sorted_numbers):
        adjacent = list(islice(same, min_repeat))
        if len(adjacent) == min_repeat:
            yield from adjacent
            yield from same
```

Пример:

```
>>> list(non_uniq_adjacent([1, 2, 3, 3, 3]))
[3, 3, 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

[collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

```
from collections import Counter
def A(numbers: list) -> list:
    '''Нужно вернуть массив, состоящий только из неуникальных элементов данного массива.
    Для этого необходимо удалить все уникальные элементы'''
    counter = Counter(numbers)
    unique = [n for n in counter if counter[n] == 1]  # уникальные элементы
    for n in unique:  # удалить все уникальные элементы
        numbers.remove(n)
    return numbers
```

Comment: Зачем так сложно-то. `return [n for n in numbers if counter[n] > 1]`

Comment: Ваше решение [также требует квадратичного `O(n*n)` времени](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/621366/%d0%92%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d1%8f%d1%89%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%be-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0/621402#comment864391_621402)