# Удаление элементов из списка. Почему не работает код?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Добрый день!
Задание было таким: 
Напишите программу, которая принимает на вход список чисел в одной строке и выводит на экран в одну строку значения, которые повторяются в нём более одного раза. Например:  Input: 4 8 0 3 4 2 0 3 Output: 0 3 4
Для решения задачи может пригодиться метод sort списка.
Выводимые числа не должны повторяться, порядок их вывода может быть произвольным.

```
a = sorted([int(n) for n in input().split(' ')])
for i in a:
    b = a.count(i)
    if b>1 :
        print(i, end=' ')
        while i in a:
            del a[a.index(i)]
```

Причем для " 1 1 2 2 3 3 3 " выводит " 1 2 3 " (все верно), а для " 1 1 2 2 3 3 " - почему-то выводит только " 1 2 ". Весь мозг уже сломала, не понимаю почему. Пожалуйста, помогите!)

Comment: Изменять коллекцию, по которой идёт итерация - это плохая практика.

Comment: Связанный вопрос [В чем разница между двумя циклами for: при удалении элементов во время обхода списка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/596463/23044)

Comment: [Вернуть массив, состоящий только из неуникальных элементов данного массива](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/621366/23044)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Т.к. ты идешь по списку a, а потом из него удаляешь элементы, то цикл for работает не правильно, так как он не может перестает ссылаться на то, что он ссылался.

```
a = sorted([int(n) for n in input().split(' ')])
for i in set(a):
    b = a.count(i)
    if b>1 :
        print(i, end=' ')
```

тут даже sort не нужен, если порядок не важен