# Уникальный элемент списка-не понятно где ошибка в коде

Tags: python, list

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]В проверки функции спотыкается на проверке.

Пример:

```
Result = 5022.69513299
5022.69513299 should equal 5022.695132990329
```

то есть дело в получаемом значении.

Сама задача состоит в том, чтобы вынуть из списка уникальный элемент (тот, который не дублируется).

```
def find_uniq(arr):
    s=[] # создаем пустой список
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        if arr.count(arr[i]) > 1: 
            # если количество повторяющихся элементов больше одного добавляем его в s список
            s.append(arr[i])
    return float(' '.join([str(i) for i in list(set(arr)-set(s))])) # вычитаем из одного списка другой,оставляя в обоих списках только уникальные элементы методом set()

test.assert_equals(find_uniq([ 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1 ]),2)
test.assert_equals(find_uniq([ 0, 0, 0.55, 0, 0 ]),0.55)
```

Comment: а какова логика работы функции find_uniq?

Comment: она ищет не продублированные элементы списка и возвращает элемент,которые не повторялся.В test.assert -примеры того,что она проверяет.Функция спотыкается на больших дробных значениях.с Decimal также не работает

Comment: опиши в своем вопросе **как** она это делает. Для редактирования вопроса используй [edit] под ним

Comment: в идеале: прокомментируй что делает каждая строка твоей функции. И добавь входные значения для которых ты получаешь свою ошибку `5022.69513299 should equal 5022.695132990329`

Comment: конкретно в каком массиве делается проверка,я не вижу.

Comment: что вернет твой код, если в массиве будет несколько пар? например: `[1,1,2,2,3]`? и что должен вернуть на самом деле?

Comment: Вообще некрасиво "всем миром" решать задачи на codewars

Comment: @AndrewKonstantinov, если количество уникальных элементов списка будет больше одного, это приведет к ошибке (`float('1 2 3')`).

Comment: @mkkik там они гарантируют,что количество уникальных элементов больше одного

Comment: @tutankhamun а что поделать,если не ясно,откуда ошибка

Comment: А если проблема только в сравнении чисел с плавающей точкой, то можно использовать `numpy.allclose` с соответсвующими параметрами точности `rtol` `atol`

Comment: @AndrewKonstantinov, я неправильно выразился. Не уникальных, а неповторяющихся.

Comment: @mkkik надо без numpy

Comment: @AndrewKonstantinov, тогда сравнивайте модуль разности с допустимым порогом.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60828/discussion-between-andrew-konstantinov-and-mkkik).

Comment: Связанный вопрос [Вернуть массив, состоящий только из неуникальных элементов данного массива](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/621366)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот реализиция на основе вашей:

```
def find_uniques(l):
    d = {}
    for elem in l:
        if elem in d:
            d[elem] += 1
        else:
            d[elem] = 1
    return [elem for elem, count in d.items() if count == 1]


print(find_uniques([1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1]))
```

Comment: в вашем случае возвращается список,а не число.  а так да,сокращенная форма ,смысл тот же

Comment: @AndrewKonstantinov Ну автор может заменить `return [...]` на `return [...][0]`, если ему это надо.

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы вернуть элемент из списка, который встречается ровно один раз (уникальный элемент) за линейное время и память (O(n) алгоритм), [можно `collections.Counter` использовать](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter

def find_uniq(numbers, default=None):
    counter = Counter(numbers)
    uniq = (n for n in numbers if counter[n] == 1)
    return next(uniq, default)
```

Пример:

```
>>> find_uniq([1, 2, 3, 1])
2
```

Answer (score 0):

Поддерживаю решение через словарь, только чуть сокращу:

```
def find_uniques(l):
  d={}
  for el in l: d[el]=d.get(el,0)+1
  return [el for el,count in d.iteritems() if count==1]
>>> find_uniques([1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1])
[2]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def find_uniq(arr):
    s = set(arr)
    for e in s:
        if arr.count(e) == 1:
            return e
```

все проще ,чем мы все думали.