# Как удалить полностью указанные элементы из списка если они встречаются два и более раз?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как удалить полностью элементы из списка если они встречаются два и более раз?
Есть функция

```
def filterList(stringList, string)
```

Она будет вызываться так:

```
filterList(['cat', 'hello', 'dog', 'hello'], 'hello')
```

надо получить

```
[‘cat’, ‘dog’]
```

Используется Python 3.5

Comment: связанный вопрос [Вернуть массив, состоящий только из неуникальных элементов данного массива](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/621366/23044) (обратная задача)

Answer (score 1):

Добавлю от себя примеры.

- `filter_list` – стандартный алгоритм
- `filter_list_2` – стандартный алгоритм, переделанный в синтаксис генератора списка
- `filter_list_3` – использование функции фильтрации, которая будет применяться к каждому элементу

Код:

```
def filter_list(items, value):
    has_more = items.count(value) > 1
    new_items = []

    for x in items:
        # Если встретили элемент и он встречается больше одного раза
        if x == value and has_more:
            continue

        new_items.append(x)

    return new_items


def filter_list_2(items, value):
    has_more = items.count(value) > 1
    return [x for x in items if not (x == value and has_more)]


def filter_list_3(items, value):
    has_more = items.count(value) > 1
    return list(filter(lambda x: not (x == value and has_more), items))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    items = ['cat', 'hello', 'dog', 'hello']
    print(filter_list(items, 'hello'))
    print(filter_list_2(items, 'hello'))
    print(filter_list_3(items, 'hello'))

    print()

    print(filter_list(items, 'cat'))
    print(filter_list_2(items, 'cat'))
    print(filter_list_3(items, 'cat'))
```

Консоль:

```
['cat', 'dog']
['cat', 'dog']
['cat', 'dog']

['cat', 'hello', 'dog', 'hello']
['cat', 'hello', 'dog', 'hello']
['cat', 'hello', 'dog', 'hello']
```

Comment: `items.count(value) > 1` желательно из цикла вытащить во всех трех вариантах. В данном случае, конечно, не сильно заметно будет, но вообще эта проверка превращает O(n) в O(n^2).

Comment: @insolor, подправил

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы полностью удалить заданную строку из списка, если она встречается более одного раза:

```
def filterList(stringList, string):
    if stringList.count(string) > 1:
        return [s for s in stringList if s != string]
    return list(stringList)
```

Это линейный алгоритм (по числу сравнений элементов), который сохраняет порядок элементов в списке. Исходный список всегда без изменений остаётся.

Можно по месту удалить (заодно переходя на PEP-8 имена):

```
def remove_if_non_uniq(lst, item):
    if lst.count(item) > 1:
        remove_all(lst, item)
```

где [`remove_all()`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/596513/23044). Это также линейный алгоритм. Обратите внимание: в этом случае функция возвращает `None`, чтобы подчеркнуть, что входной список может измениться. [По ссылке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/596513/23044) также проиллюстрирована разница между линейным и квадратичными алгоритмами, о которой полезно знать.

Answer (score 0):

Удалить полностью все элементы из списка, если они встречаются два и более раз, можно так:

```
from collections import Counter

z = ['cat', 'hello', 'dog', 'hello']
print ([k for (k, v) in Counter(z).items() if v == 1])
```

Не до конца понятно, зачем параметр... 
Если хотите, чтобы правило работало только для определенной строки:

```
from collections import Counter

z = ['cat', 'hello', 'dog', 'hello', 'dog', 'parrot']
def filterList(l, s):
    return list(set(l) - set([k for (k, v) in Counter(l).items() if v > 1 and s in k]))

print (filterList(z, 'hello'))
```

Comment: В set генератор списка можно заменить просто на генератор, пример: `set([k for k, v in items])` -> `set(k for k, v in items)`

Comment: 1- первый пример не сохраняет порядок элементов в списке (Counter не упорядочен в Питоне). Чтобы сохранить порядок, [поправьте условие в коде](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/621477/23044) 2- второй пример: сразу несколько вещей неверны. Подумайте, что вы бы хотели получить, к примеру, для `filterList(['cat', 'dog', 'hello', 'cat', 'hello'], 'hello')`? [Сравните результаты](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/705457/23044)

Comment: @jfs про порядок ничего не сказано, что во втором неверно? задачу выполняет...