# Принцип работы словаря Python

Tags: python-3.x, словари

```
a = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
d={b: a.count(b) for b in a}
for i in d:
    if d[i]>1:
        print(i, end=' ')
```

Почему при генерации словаря(при заданной строке с повторяющимися элементами

```
('1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3' например)
```

в словаре создается только одну пару "Число":"Кол-во повторений"?

Comment: Потому что ключи словаря не могут повторяться

Comment: , так же как и массивах/списках не могут повторяться индексы

Comment: Связанный вопрос [Вернуть массив, состоящий только из неуникальных элементов данного массива](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/621366/23044)