# Заход в цикл и удаление элемента списка

Tags: python, циклы

Всем привет, 
Пытаясь сделать задание с checkio, наткнулся на проблему - 
задание заключается в удалении всех уникальных элементов
при выполнении данного цикла - удаление из списка, при списке состоящем из цифр, каждый второй раз не заходит в цикл

Я попробовал поменять ввести копию списка, полагая что изменения в самом списке приводят к сбою в цикле, но это не помогло.

Проверил на списке другого типа, такая же ошибка.

Причем ошибка появляется, только когда цикл идет по списку, который передается в функцию, если список берется извне, то ошибки нету. Список в процессе цикла не меняется. Почему тогда происходит ошибка?

*Питон я изучать начал буквально недавно, и возможно ответ лежит на поверхности, но логически я до него дойти не могу, а разобраться интересно.

```
def checkio(data):

    data1 = data # копия списка во избежание изменений

    print (len(data1)) # определяет длину списка - всегда правильно

    for i in data: #заменить на fruits

        print (data.count(i)) # не выводит каждый второй элемент передаваемого списка

        if data.count(i) == 1:

            data1.remove(i)

    return data1

    fruits = ['banana', 'apple',  'mango'] # список строк для проверки

    data2 = [1, 2, 3] # исходный список

    print (checkio(data2))
```

Comment: не знаю почему меня так сильно раздражает, когда списки в  Python называют "массивами". Список и массив - разные вещи.

Comment: В школе учил паскаль, сейчас сел за питон, старые привычки, а так да, список, спасибо

Comment: И -да! @hichock, не забывайте на сайте --checkio-- читать чужие решения. Там есть чему поучиться "в любом возрасте"! ;-)

Comment: Да, спасибо, как раз прошел первое задание, глянул лучшее решение и понял что все еще впереди)
Питон конечно удивительно удобный язык

Comment: связанный вопрос [Вернуть массив, состоящий только из неуникальных элементов данного массива](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/621366/23044)

Answer (score 2):

Дело в том, что в этой строке

```
data1 = data  # копия списка во избежание изменений
```

вы не копируете список, а лишь присваиваете переменной `data1` ссылку на список, хранящийся в переменной `data`. Т.е. эти переменные ссылаются на один и тот же объект. Так что при удалении элемента из списка `data1`, он точно также удаляется и из `data`, это вообще один и тот же список.

По-настоящему скопировать список можно [несколькими способами](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2612815/7485582).

1. `data1 = data[:]  # берём срез всех элементов списка data`
2. `data1 = list(data)  # создаём новый список из элементов старого`
3. ```
   import copy
   def checkio(data):
       data1 = copy.copy(data)  # пользуемся специальным методом из модуля copy
   ```

Comment: Точно, забыл что копировать не так, спасибо всем!

Answer (score 2):

Все довольно просто.
Ваши `data1 = data` "прикреплены" к одному и тому же объекту.
Рекомендую предварительно выполнять задачи вот на этом сайте: 
http://pythontutor.com/live.html#mode=edit   - 
там визуализируется происходящее в "памяти" при выполнении вашего кода.
Итого - ваша копирование не сохранило список. Работа ведется в нем же, но через другое имя. Вот картинка, где я ввел часть вашего кода:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]